# How to reshape 2D image into 3D in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

mask_red = np.load('C:/Users/kjbaili/.spyder-py3/GMM/gmm_color_object_detection- 
master/roipoly_annotate/Neuer Ordner/2.2.npy')

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/kjbaili/.spyder-py3/GMM/gmm_color_object_detection- 
master/roipoly_annotate/Neuer Ordner/2.2.png')

pixel_red = img[mask_red]

print(pixel_red.shape)

cv2.imshow('red_pixel',pixel_red)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

img has shape of (900x1200x3)
mask_red is an (900x1200) array.

pixel_red is the extracted roi containing only red pixels ans has the shape (51605,3)
What I'm trying to do is to view the pixel_red as an image using imshow and therefore it needs to be reshaped to (height,width,channels).

Please note when i view pixel_red as it is i get an uninterpretable rectangular line which makes sense due to the actuall shape of the red_pixel

So anyone know how to view the image correctly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

To display red channel of img use this (imread load in BGR format thats why 2)

```
   pixel_red = img[:,:,2]
```

Comment: thanks for the replay. please note that pixel_red is not an image, it's a binary file that contains shape and dtype information necessary to reconstruct the array correctly